# How to find all paths using dfs on undirected adjacency list

Tags: path, depth-first-search

I am trying to find all possible paths from source to destination from an adjacencylist. For example, if my starting node is 1 and my target node is 5, I would expect to get [1,2,3,4,5] and [1,2,6,7,8,5] as viable paths.

My code below can find only one of these viable paths, but I am not sure how to get the other path. My main problem is, after I had found one path, pretty much all the nodes have already been visited, and I don't know how to pop the nodes without going into infinite recursion.

```py
    adjacencylist={1:[2],2:[1,6,3],3:[2,4],4:[3,8,5],5:[4],6:[2,7],7:[6,8],8:[7,4]}
    visited=[]
    viablepaths=[]
    
    
    def dfs(graph,start,target,path,output):
        if start in visited:
            return
        visited.append(start)
        
        if start==target:
            output.append(path)
            
            viablepaths.extend(output)
            
            return
        for nx in graph[start]:
            dfs(graph,nx,target,path+[nx],output)
            
        
        return 
    
    dfs(adjacencylist,1,5,[1],[])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your code. When you visit node you mark it as visited by adding to `visited` list. However, you never really remove nodes from this list. It means if node is reachable via some path it won't be processed during traversing via other path. Simple solution here is to remove nodes from `visited` after traversing its children. You can't really remove whole `visited` list as you correctly mentioned to avoid loops

Updated code (also refactored for readability and added comments):

```py
adjacencylist = {1:[2], 2:[1,6,3], 3:[2,4], 4:[3,8,5], 5:[4], 6:[2,7], 7:[6,8], 8:[7,4]}
visited = set()  # check in set is O(1) compared to O(N) in list
viablepaths = []
    
    
def dfs(graph, start, target, path):
    if start in visited:
        return
        
    if start == target:
        viablepaths.append(path)
        return
    
    visited.add(start)  # start to process current node
    
    for nx in graph[start]:
        dfs(graph, nx, target, path + [nx])  # this dfs will never reach curr node because it's marked as visited
            
    visited.remove(start)  # finish current node processing
    
dfs(adjacencylist,1,5,[1])
print(viablepaths)
```

Output:

> [[1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]